# Php delete all jpg but 20 newest

Tags: php, unlink, filemtime

So.. I've been looking around, but not really found what I need, so here goes:

I got a webcam set to upload jpg's to a folder, but to avoid my server getting overflown with files, I want to clean out all jpg's but 20 newest when I load the page that shows the pictures.
If the page loads, and there are only 20 jpg's in the folder, it should do nothing.

Comment: Can you show us any of the code you've tried ?

Comment: please take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113145/delete-all-files-inside-a-folder-but-the-last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

1. Get last modified time of each file using `filemtime($filename);`
2. Sort all filenames into an array based on this date.
3. Delete all files except the first 20 using `unlink()`

Some variations of what you need: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113145/delete-all-files-inside-a-folder-but-the-last), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205738/how-to-delete-files-from-directory-based-on-creation-date-in-php), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126191/php-script-to-delete-files-older-than-24-hrs-deletes-all-files)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I wasnt able to find that first one you linked :)